# Ksh93 backtick behavior difference

Tags: ksh

Can anyone explain the difference in behavior below?

**ksh 93t + coreutils-6.12:**

```
> cat test.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
> abc=1
> head -`expr $abc + 3` test.txt
1
2
3
4
> cat test.txt | head -`expr $abc + 3`
1
2
3
4
```

**ksh 93u + coreutils 8.12:**

```
> cat test.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
> abc=1
> head -`expr $abc + 3` test.txt
1
2
3
4
> cat test.txt | head -`expr $abc + 3`    1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: you're right, that doesn't look right. Does turning on `set -vx` debugging show anything of interest? But.. backticks are marked as deprecated at least since the 1995 book 'The New KornShell Command And Programming Language (2nd Edition)', so why not move up to the 90s and use `$(.. myCmd ..)` cmd-substition :-) ? Good luck.

Comment: Agreed! Replacing expr for $(()) works just fine also. Thanks for the references. I'll help build my case here :)